# How to know the compliant google-cloud-* packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, package

Is there any way to know the Python google-cloud-* packages that are compliant which eachothers and so that don't have dependencies versions conflicts?

For example, according to the following 2 errors we can conclude that the two packages (**google-cloud-storage 1.31.0**  and **google-cloud-bigquery 1.24.0**) are not compliant with eachother because of the version of **google-resumable-media** required for eachone:

```
google-cloud-storage 1.31.0 depends on google-resumable-media<2.0dev and >=1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery 1.24.0 depends on google-resumable-media<0.6dev and >=0.5.0
```

No version can be higher than 1.0.0 and lower than 0.6dev...

This was an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "compliant"? Compliant with what?

Comment: I have done an edit to explain. It's weird to get downvotes without knowing the reason. Thank you for asking, I appreciate it.

Comment: The edit does help a lot. One more question: can you clarify further the term "compliant" in this context? Is there a specific regulation you're trying to comply with (e.g. GDPR)?

Comment: More details. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.

Comment: Those are not the latest library versions. Try using google-cloud-storage 1.32.0 and google-cloud-bigquery 2.2.0. Those are the latest versions, and do not appear to have any problems both being used together.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't without looking at the project's changelog, source code or just manually increasing the version of `google-cloud-bigquery`.

In this case, `google-cloud-bigquery` started supporting `google-resumable-media<2.0dev` in version `1.26.1`: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/changelog.html#id29